# How can I start an intent from a card in Google Glass

Tags: android, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I've tried this app, Crystal Shopper :

https://crystalshopper.herokuapp.com/

which seems to be able to start an application from a card.

As you can see in this screenshot

https://crystalshopper.herokuapp.com/static/images/barcode_search.png

there seems to be a command called

crystalshopper://open

Source seems unavailable, so I must infer...

Is correct to assume that this is simply an action which, through the Mirror API, tells the server to send a special notification to the device, which is detected by a BroadcastListener, which will then launch the required Intent?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965155/opening-gdk-glassware-through-mirror-api-glassware-menuitem/20977865#20977865)
is was work for me.Using this methos we can send data also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an APK installed on Glass registers a custom URI scheme, Mirror API Glassware can launch it by using a menu item with the `OPEN_URI` action. Set the `payload` attribute of the menu item to the custom URI and it will launch the appropriate activity when tapped.

Comment: VIEW_WEBSITE action is now 'OPEN_URI'

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that VIEW_WEBSITE is now deprecated in favor of OPEN_URI. VIEW_WEBSITE will be removed in a future release.

Comment: But I could not find the payload attribute in c# mirror api. is there an alternative?