# Linking Mirror Api and GDK glassware App

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I am Trying to launch a GDK App on my glass using a MenuItem on Timeline card inserted through Mirror API. I have Tired all the possible way to make it work there might be a logical bug I couldn't catch.

I followed these links as my starting point.

[Opening GDK Glassware through Mirror API Glassware MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965155/opening-gdk-glassware-through-mirror-api-glassware-menuitem/20977865#20977865)

[Menu Item for "OPEN_URI" not present in menuItems return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105005/menu-item-for-open-uri-not-present-in-menuitems-return)

[How can I start an intent from a card in Google Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790374/how-can-i-start-an-intent-from-a-card-in-google-glass)

Mirror API Code fragment.

```
List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
            // Built in actions
            menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setAction("NAVIGATE"));
            menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setAction("DELETE"));

            List<MenuValue> values= new ArrayList<MenuValue>();
            //values.add(new MenuValue().setDisplayName("remember").setState("DEFAULT"));
            values.add(new MenuValue().setDisplayName("remembering").setState("LAUNCHER"));

            menuItemList.add(new 
          MenuItem().setAction("OPEN_URI").setPayload("exampleprotocol").setValues(values));
            timelineItem.setMenuItems(menuItemList);
```

GDK App(Manifest file)

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.rajeev.memory.ElephantService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_plus_50"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="exampleprotocol"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
        </service>
```

However, I could launch google website using OPEN_URI Action with "Payload" :"https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet's `setPayload()` call, use `exampleprotocol://`.

Comment: The MenuItem doesn't get displayed if I use setAction("OPEN_URI") with setPayload("exampleprotocol://") , However it gets displayed if I use setAction("CUSTOM") but doesn't launch the app instead it refreshes the card.